# why is onload event of img not fired?

Tags: javascript, image, events, onload

I attached an `onload` event to an imgage created by `new image();`
But the `onload` event seems to be never fired. The `console.log` inside the function which should be run when `onload` is fired is never displayed.

I also tried to use `addEventListener` instead of `.onload`. but it doesn't work either.

```
function init(){
    var main_canvas = document.getElementById('main_canvas');
    var bg_canvas = document.getElementById('background_canvas');

    if(main_canvas.getContext){
        var ctx = main_canvas.getContext('2d');
        var bg_ctx = bg_canvas.getContext('2d');

        let ball = new Image();   
        let box = new Image();

        console.log(ball);
        ball.onload = function() {
            console.log('positiv');
            bg_ctx.drawImage(box,150,100);
            bg_ctx.drawImage(box,150,600);
            ctx.drawImage(ball,350,125);
        }
        ball.src = 'ball.png';
        box.src = 'box.png';
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', init);
```

Expected output should be: 1)  (because of `console.log(ball);`) This works fine.

2) output: positiv (because `ball.onload` is fired) BUT THIS NEVER HAPPENS!!

Comment: You're sure the `.png` files are found - not 404?

Comment: yes they exist and could be adressed

Comment: Had to ask :-) - anyway, there is no answer to your question given the code you've provided. This is easily demonstrated with images that are known to be in place: https://jsbin.com/balawajipi/1/edit?js,console